# JQUERY UI .auto-complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need a little bit of help. I am trying to add jQuery UI autocomplete,

```
$("#search").autocomplete({ source: $post });
```

To the code below and I am not to sure how to go about on doing it..

```
// Communication to PHP file

function searchq() {    
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();

    $.post("tagasearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output){
        $("#output").html(output);
    });
};
```

They way the code right now works is it prints out to HTML in the form of

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not including the proper css in your page?  Also I'm not sure about just putting $post as the source. I usually do something like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="search">

 <script>
    jQuery('#search').autocomplete({
       source: function(request, response) {    

          jQuery.ajax({ url: toCall,
             dataType: "json",
             data: { term: request.term },
             success: function(data) {
                response(data);
              }
          });

     } //whatever other setup you want for autocomplete like minLength, etc.
   });

 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just used the code $("#search").autocomplete({ source: $post }); as a example.. I was wondering what to use for the source right now in my PHP script I have "output" echo to my jquery. For the css I have the right jquery ui file linked to my HTLM page.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25940702/2685386) is correct, but doesn't explain much. I'll try to expand on it a bit.

First off, note that `$("#search")` is an `id` selector, not a `name`. If your input only has a `name=search` you can select it with `$("[name=search]")`

Next, it looks like your PHP page expects a parameter called `searchVal`. If you rewrite it to expect `term` (which is autocomplete's default `request` parameter), you can go as simple as passing your post's URL to the `source` option:

```
$("input[name=search]").autocomplete({ source: "tagasearch.php" });
```

Third, if you use the `search: function()` option value you can customize it or its response (like Scott suggests):

```
$("input[name=search]").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      $.post("tagasearch.php", {
            searchVal: request.term
            //                ^-- request.term is the string you've typed in the input
      }, response);
      // ^-- response is the callback passed by jQueryUI
      //
      // it expects a single parameter which it treats as the data for the widget

      // Just using response in the above function is exactly equivalent to:
      $.post("tagasearch.php", {searchVal: request.term},
           function(output) {
               response(output);
           }
      );
 }
```

[The documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) has all the info you need; there's also [a couple of useful examples](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)